How to copy merged cells with VBA
I have 2 Excel file with same format but one is Master file (for calculating) and one file is extracted data from system. I want to copy extracted file's data to Master file with VBA but it didn't work.
File format looks like below:

So I want to Copy from A1 to I200 and then Paste it to Master file but it raised error "To do this, all the merged cells need to be the same size" or "PasteSpecial method of Range class failed".
Below is my sample code:
Sub TransferData()

Dim main_wb As Workbook
Dim target_wb As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set main_wb = Workbooks.Open("C:/Users/admin/Documents/Sample.xlsx")
main_sheet = "Sheet1"

Set target_wb = ThisWorkbook
target_sheet = "Sheet1"

main_wb.Sheets(main_sheet).Range("A1:I200").Copy
target_wb.Sheets(target_sheet).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

What should I do to copy merged cells? Thank you.

You can copy values that way, but only if the destination sheet has no merged cells or if all merge areas are the same as the source. If the destination has different merged cells, you get the error you mention and you need first make up your mind how you want to deal with that.

I'm trying to copy to the destination that has same as the source but it raised errors.

If raises errors if the destination already contains merged cells and the merge areas are different from the source - try this with Excel (not with VBA) manually, you will get the same error. What do you want to do with that merged cells at the destination?

@FunThomas: it's quite strange. I'm sure that destination and source has the same format (including merged cells). What do you want to do with that merged cells at the destination? -> it's not important, it can be unmerge or merge.

If you want to copy only data, instead of using Copy and PasteSpecial, read the data into a 2-dimensional array and write the array data into the destination. This will keep the formatting of the destination intact, including merged areas. It will not throw an error if the destination contains merged areas that are different form the source.
If the source and the destination have the same merged area, everything is fine anyhow (marked green).
If the source contains a merged area where the destination has single (unmerged) cells, only the first cell of the destination is filled (marked yellow).
If the source contains single cells where the destination has a merged array, the value of the first cell is copied (marked red).
Source data:

Destination (after copy):

Your code could look like this:
Dim sourceRange As Range, destRange As Range
Set sourceRange = main_wb.Sheets(main_sheet).Range("A1:I200")
Set destRange = target_wb.Sheets(target_sheet).Range("A1").Resize(sourceRange.Rows.Count, sourceRange.Columns.Count)

Dim data As Variant
data = sourceRange.Value
destRange.Value = data


I have another question. What if I want to copy more sheet? I will need to set sourceRange, destRange, data for each sheets? For example main_sheet_2, target_sheet_2

Yes, that's basically it. Just try it.
